# Navigation based on roles in ReactJs App with SpringBoot

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

I'm trying to learn ReactJS and SpringBoot. Now I'm working on a small project. However I've encountered an issue. I use Spring Security to generate JWT Tokens for authentication in my project. I have specified a certain email and password, when inputted into the login form will generate a token that has payload with Role defined as "ADMIN". If any other data is inputted, it will generate token with Role defined as "USER". Now the issue is if the admin credentials are entered the token is generated and it navigates to "/dash" in the frontend and if any user credentials are entered that is navigated to "/dash" as well. How do I set the page to navigate to "/admin" if the admin credentials are given

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import '../assets/css/login.css';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setEmail } from '../redux/Actions';
import Header from './Header/Header';
import axios from 'axios';
const Login = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  });

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  
  const isEmailValid = (email) => {
    const emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    return emailPattern.test(email);
  };
  
  const isPasswordValid = (password) => {
    return password.length >= 8;
  };
  
  const handleLogin = async () => {
    const { email, password } = formData;
    
    if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
      toast.error('Invalid email address', {
        position: 'top-right',
        autoClose: 3000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
      });
      return;
    }
    
    if (!isPasswordValid(password)) {
      toast.error('Password must be at least 8 characters long', {
        position: 'bottom-center',
        autoClose: 3000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
      });
      return;
    }
    
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/login', {
        email: formData.email,
        password: formData.password,
      });
      console.log('Login Response:', response);

      if (response.status === 200) {
        const token = response.data.token;
        const userEmail = formData.email;
        dispatch(setEmail(userEmail));
        
        localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'true');
        localStorage.setItem('userEmail', userEmail);
        localStorage.setItem('authToken', token);

        toast.success('Login successful!', {
          position: 'bottom-center',
          autoClose: 3000,
          hideProgressBar: false,
          closeOnClick: true,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          draggable: true,
        });

        if (response.data.role === 'ADMIN') {
          navigate('/admin');
        } else {
          navigate('/dash');
        }
      } else {
        toast.error('Login failed. Please try again.', {
          position: 'bottom-center',
          autoClose: 3000,
          hideProgressBar: false,
          closeOnClick: true,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          draggable: true,
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      toast.error('An error occurred while logging in. Please try again.', {
        position: 'bottom-center',
        autoClose: 3000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='main_login'>
      <Header />
      <div className="login_cont">
        <h1 className='login_title'>Login</h1>
        <form>
          <input type='text' name="email" id="email" className='input-fieldx' placeholder='Email' onChange={handleChange} required />
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" className='input-fieldx' placeholder='Password' onChange={handleChange} required />
          <div className="form-button-container">
            <button type="button" className="login-btn" onClick={handleLogin}>
              Login
            </button>
          </div>
          <p className='no_acc'> <Link to="/register">Don't have an account?</Link></p>
        </form>
      </div>
      <ToastContainer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

I have tried giving `response.data.role === 'ADMIN'` but it doesn't seem to work.